# I am getting nil while parsing JSON with Swift

Tags: json, swift, parsing

I am learning Swift and I am studying for parsing JSON. I have a little complicated API for me and I can't get data from it. Can you let me know what mistakes I do below?

```
import UIKit


struct DataSource: Codable {
    let status: Int
    let totalResults: String
    let articles: [Articles]
}

struct Articles: Codable {
    let source: [Source]
    let author: String
    let title: String
}

struct Source: Codable {
    let name: String
}

let source = URL(string: "http://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=bitcoin&from=2020-03-29&sortBy=publishedAt&apiKey=51480e6fd4294010d")!
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: source) { (data, response, error ) in

    if let data = data {

        let publishing = try? JSONDecoder().decode([DataSource].self, from: data)
        print(publishing)



    }
}.resume()
```

[image]

Comment: Some mistakes: you are using `try?` instead of `try` which means you are ignoring any errors which is a really bad mistake, you are expecting an array of DataSource but it seems like it is a single instance, you have included your pivate api key in the code you have posted so now anyone can  use it, you have posted an image of your json response instead of text which makes it harder for us to help you.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed! Thank u for your all recommandations. Appreciated!

```
import UIKit
```

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

    struct DataSource: Codable {
        let status: String?
        let totalResults: Int?
        let articles: [Articles]
    }

    struct Articles: Codable {
        let source: Source
        let author: String
        let title: String
    }

    struct Source: Codable {
        let id: String?
        let name: String
    }

    let source = URL(string: "http://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=bitcoin&from=2020-03-30&sortBy=publishedAt&apiKey=XXXXXX")!
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: source) { (data, response, error ) in

        do
        {
            let publishing = try JSONDecoder().decode(DataSource.self, from: data!)

            print(publishing)
        }
        catch
        {
            print(error)
        }



    } .resume()


}
```

}

Answer (score 0):

I make this example on playground

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport


// MARK: - ProfileResponse
struct ArticlesResponse: Codable {
    var status: String
    var totalResults: Int
    var articles: [Article]
}

// MARK: - ProfileArticle
struct Article: Codable {
    var source: Source
    var author: String?
    var title, articleDescription: String
    var url: String
    var urlToImage: String?
    var publishedAt: String
    var content: String?

    enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case source, author, title
        case articleDescription = "description"
        case url, urlToImage, publishedAt, content
    }
}

// MARK: - ProfileSource
struct Source: Codable {
    var id: String?
    var name: String
}


class MyViewController : UIViewController {
    override func loadView() {
        let view = UIView()
        view.backgroundColor = .white

        let label = UILabel()
        label.frame = CGRect(x: 150, y: 200, width: 200, height: 20)
        label.text = "Hello World!"
        label.textColor = .black

        view.addSubview(label)
        self.view = view

        if let url = URL(string: "http://newsapi.org/v2/everything?q=bitcoin&from=2020-03-30&sortBy=publishedAt&apiKey=f0b7d2e59beb4bcdb7a737a25c3542bc") {
           URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
              if let data = data {
                  do {
                     let decoder = JSONDecoder()
                     let data = try decoder.decode(ArticlesResponse.self, from: data)
                    label.text = "\(data.status)"
                  } catch let error {
                     print(error)
                  }
               }
           }.resume()
        }
    }
}
// Present the view controller in the Live View window
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = MyViewController()
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Enzo , Do u think I can run my codes on playground or i have to run it as a project?

Comment: Playground is good to learn Swift language, but when you start with UI need to use a project. I only used playground to exemplify something specific and prove the code in one minute.